# How can I get the polygon clicked on in ti.map on iOS?

Tags: ios, dictionary, polygon, appcelerator-titanium

I have a simple map where I draw some polygons. Then I want to capture if the user clicks on a polygon - and get a handle to that polygon (e.g. by a custom id of the polygon or similar).

I use code like this to add the polygon:

```
    var poly = Map.createPolygon({
        points : points,
        id : 'poly',
        fillColor : '#55ec858f',
        strokeColor : 'black',
        strokeWidth : 2
    });
    mapView.addPolygon(poly);
```

where `points` is an array of latitude/longitude objects. I have registered a click handler:

```
mapView.addEventListener('click',clickHandler);
```

... and it is defined like this:

```
function clickHandler(e){
    console.log("click: id=" + e.source.id + ", source=" + JSON.stringify(e.source));
    console.log("click: clicksource=" + e.clicksource + ", latitude=" + e.latitude + ", longitude=" + e.longitude);
}
```

The click handler is triggered once I click within the polygon (well, more correctly it is triggered *wherever* on the map I click). This is fine. However, on iOS I cannot identify which of the polygons the user clicked on. The output looks like this:

```
[INFO] :   click: id=undefined, source={"horizontalWrap":true,"visible":true,"mapType":1,"rotateEnabled":false,"region":{"longitudeDelta":0.010248234495520592,"latitudeDelta":0.009999999776482582,"longitude":11.154247283935547,"latitude":55.55887985229492}}
[INFO] :   click: clicksource=polygon, latitude=55.55712556278878, longitude=11.154479577247997
```

On Android I get what I want:

```
[INFO] :   click: id=poly, source={"fillColor":"#55ec858f","strokeColor":"black","points":[{"latitude":55.563299,"longitude":11.157998},{"latitude":55.562731,"longitude":11.157987},{"latitude":55.562719,"longitude":11.158029},{"latitude":55.562648,"longitude":11.158027},{"latitude":55.562153,"longitude":11.157851},{"latitude":55.561301,"longitude":11.157834},{"latitude":55.561088,"longitude":11.157913},{"latitude":55.560212,"longitude":11.157896},{"latitude":55.560106,"longitude":11.157935},{"latitude":55.559751,"longitude":11.157928},{"latitude":55.559515,"longitude":11.157882},{"latitude":55.559267,"longitude":11.157731},{"latitude":55.559184,"longitude":11.15775},{"latitude":55.559018,"longitude":11.15783},{"latitude":55.558899,"longitude":11.157953},{"latitude":55.558686,"longitude":11.157928},{"latitude":55.558604,"longitude":11.157864},{"latitude":55.558391,"longitude":11.157859},{"latitude":55.558143,"longitude":11.157834},{"latitude":55.557694,"longitude":11.157804},{"latitude":55.557233,"longitude":11.15769},{"latitude":55.556985,"longitude":11.157623},{"latitude":55.556678,"longitude":11.157513},{"latitude":55.556266,"longitude":11.157317},{"latitude":55.556041,"longitude":11.157291},{"latitude":55.555828,"longitude":11.157245},{"latitude":55.555592,"longitude":11.157157},{"latitude":55.555144,"longitude":11.156961},{"latitude":55.554779,"longitude":11.156786},{"latitude":55.554507,"longitude":11.156677},{"latitude":55.554401,"longitude":11.156675},{"latitude":55.554366,"longitude":11.156632},{"latitude":55.554385,"longitude":11.156451},{"latitude":55.554447,"longitude":11.155964},{"latitude":55.554525,"longitude":11.155484},{"latitude":55.554621,"longitude":11.155014},{"latitude":55.554733,"longitude":11.154556},{"latitude":55.554862,"longitude":11.154111},{"latitude":55.555005,"longitude":11.153681},{"latitude":55.555164,"longitude":11.153268},{"latitude":55.555337,"longitude":11.152873},{"latitude":55.555524,"longitude":11.152498},{"latitude":55.555724,"longitude":11.152145},{"latitude":55.555936,"longitude":11.151815},{"latitude":55.556159,"longitude":11.151509},{"latitude":55.556393,"longitude":11.151228},{"latitude":55.556636,"longitude":11.150974},{"latitude":55.556887,"longitude":11.150747},{"latitude":55.557147,"longitude":11.150549},{"latitude":55.557412,"longitude":11.150379},{"latitude":55.557684,"longitude":11.15024},{"latitude":55.557959,"longitude":11.150131},{"latitude":55.558238,"longitude":11.150053},{"latitude":55.55852,"longitude":11.150006},{"latitude":55.558802,"longitude":11.14999},{"latitude":55.559084,"longitude":11.150006},{"latitude":55.559366,"longitude":11.150053},{"latitude":55.559645,"longitude":11.150131},{"latitude":55.55992,"longitude":11.15024},{"latitude":55.560192,"longitude":11.150379},{"latitude":55.560457,"longitude":11.150549},{"latitude":55.560717,"longitude":11.150747},{"latitude":55.560968,"longitude":11.150974},{"latitude":55.561211,"longitude":11.151228},{"latitude":55.561445,"longitude":11.151509},{"latitude":55.561668,"longitude":11.151815},{"latitude
[INFO] :   click: clicksource=polygon, latitude=55.55844486621942, longitude=11.154376566410065
```

The `id` is really enough for me to get the relevant data (and be able to show the user some more details about the area).

I have tried to add an event handler to the polygon - but it does not work (and *really* I would want to use *one* global event listener as in the example above).

I think the only thing I have not tried yet is to try to calculate which polygon I am inside based on the GPS points... I am not really good at such geometric arithmetic - so would like not to go down that road if possible ;-)

Any good ideas?

Thanks in advance!

***Edited:***

*Forgot to mention platform...*

```
Appc CLI 5.1.0 
Studio: 4.4.0
ti.map: 2.3.6 (Android)
ti.map: 2.5.2 (iOS)
```

/John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use e.shape.title

I do it like this:

`map.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    Ti.API.info('You clicked ' + JSON.stringify(e.shape.title));
});`

I can't remember what is available on the e.shape, but i guess you should be able to find an id, or something else to identify your polygon.

Comment: Thanks! That works. I can add my own properties on the polygon so it is easy to get a handle on the right one :-)  I had found another solution to work around the problem. I use `Turf` to work with the geo-data - and used that to find out if a point was inside one of the polygons. But this is cleaner ;-)